# Put html forms inline with boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

right now I am trying to put 2 forms in line using boostrap grid system and it does not work and I do not understand why. I did exactly as they say in their documentation and still nothing. Here is my html code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="container-fluid bg">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <form class="form-container">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h2>Idea X</h2>
                        <h4>Descriere proiect: </h4>
                        <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ullamcorper orci nec sapien ultricies, et auctor elit molestie. Fusce non est felis.</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Limbaje folosite: </label>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">HTML5</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">CSS3</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">JavaScript</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">AngularJS</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Vreau sa particip</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <form class="form-container">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h2>Idea X</h2>
                        <h4>Descriere proiect: </h4>
                        <label>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ullamcorper orci nec sapien ultricies, et auctor elit molestie. Fusce non est felis.</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Limbaje folosite: </label>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">HTML5</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">CSS3</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">JavaScript</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">AngularJS</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Vreau sa particip</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

any help would be awesome, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `<div class="row">` and `<div class="form-group col-xs-6">`